# CloudFormation AWS::RDS::DBInstance Error "Specifying IOPs is not allowed for this engine"

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have this CloudFormation code

```
  DatabasePrimaryInstanceAurora0:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Condition: IsEnvPRO
    Properties:
      Engine: aurora-postgresql
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref Aurora0
      DBInstanceClass: db.t4g.medium
      DBInstanceIdentifier: postgres0-0
      DBSubnetGroupName: rds1
      StorageType: gp3
```

According with this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbinstance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-storagetype , we are good to go but I got that error from cloudFormation

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid storage type: gp3 (Service: Rds, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 6b75124d-2e57-47fd-bbf3-54ab4f217a82)" (RequestToken: f72ffede-b654-a065-0c5e-cf91c05473d9, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

Thanks to @9bO3av5fw5 I added

```
      Iops: 3000
```

But then I got...

```
Resource handler returned message: "Specifying IOPs is not allowed for this engine (Service: Rds, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 2a558dd8-9e6c-47c8-bef0-af674f05760b)" (RequestToken: 53f0e15e-53b7-d9f5-4817-9d2dcc34bef3, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

My Engine:

```
     Engine: aurora-postgresql
     EngineMode: provisioned
```

Comment: Per the docs you link...
If you specify io1 or gp3, you must also include a value for the Iops parameter.

Comment: @9bO3av5fw5, you are rigth.

Comment: I hadn't noticed the instance vs cluster bit though - interesting, perhaps still work in progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer is here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html

> General Purpose SSD gp3 storage is supported on Single-AZ and Multi-AZ DB instances, but isn't supported on Multi-AZ DB clusters. For more information, see Multi-AZ deployments for high availability and Multi-AZ DB cluster deployments.

Answer (score -1):

Aurora has its own storage. It doesn't use the same storage types as RDS. You can't specify gp3 as storage for Aurora databases.

Comment: Sorry, you are wrong. As you can see I choosed 'StorageType: gp3' without problem. Please read my post carefully the link I attached included.

Comment: I'm not wrong.  I read your post. It's just the way the parameters are being checked. The error is coming from the fact that you chose gp3. Aurora uses a completely different storage mechanism and doesn't support gp3. Go look at the docs and the AWS calculator. Aurora doesn't allow up to enter the storage type because it has its own storage. If you leave off "StorageType: gp3" and enter the iops, it should work.

Comment: From the doc referenced in the question above in the StorageType section but just a little further down: Amazon Aurora

Not applicable. Aurora data is stored in the cluster volume, which is a single, virtual volume that uses solid state drives (SSDs).